# Shrink a webpage to fit the iframe dimension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bsp

I am trying to fit the contents of the webpage into an iframe whose dimensions are fixed.

I need to resize the page such that the complete page fits in the given dimensions of the iframe without truncation.

And I do not need scrollbar, the page should fit without a scrollbar.

I have tried something like this, but didn't work.

```
<iframe width="650" height="350" src="http://www.bbc.co.uk" style="-ms-transform: scale(,);"></iframe>
```

Comment: Not possible for sites on domain other than the one you have the iframe in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannnot. you options would be use site speicfic css to reduce the size of elements.

if you don't want scroll-bars try overflow:hidden css property.

Check this [stack overflow duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630308/possible-to-shrink-contents-of-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

As given dimensions of iframe , you don't need scroll bar , So just add scrolling="no"

Check this

```
<iframe width="650" height="350" scrolling="no" src="http://www.bbc.co.uk"></iframe>
```

Preeti Chawla,
[Web developer](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/brochure/Web-2.0-Design)