# How to shrink contents to fit inside an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

So I have a very large image, and I am trying to display it in an iframe. I want to shrink the image so it fits inside the iframe without scroll bars. I tried following the advice here: [possible to shrink contents of iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630308/possible-to-shrink-contents-of-iframe)

However, this simply shrunk the size of the iframe itself, not its content. Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using <iframe> and not something like <figure> or even <div> ? <iframe> tags are mostly used to embed content from an external web page.

Comment: @RobinBaby I need it to support pdf documents as well so I am not sure if those other options would work