# change width of iframe src

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this `iframe`

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #F2EEE9;
    font: normal 13px/1.5 Georgia, Serif;
    color: #333;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 705px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.items {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.item {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 205px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 290px;
}
.item img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
button {
    border: 1px solid #722A1B;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #722A1B;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span {
    float: right;
}
.shopping-cart {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/24/_cart.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic);

/* Override UGG site */
#main {width: 100%; padding:0;}
.content-asset p {margin:0 auto;}
.breadcrumb {display:none;}

/* Helpers */
/**************************/
.margin-top-10 {padding-top:10px;}
.margin-bot-10 {padding-bottom:10px;}

/* Typography */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg h1 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:24px; font-weight:400; text-transform: uppercase; padding:0; margin:0;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg h2 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:70px; letter-spacing:10px; text-align:center; color:white; font-weight:400; text-transform:uppercase; z-index:10; opacity:.9;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg h3 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:0; font-weight:400; letter-spacing:8px; text-transform: uppercase; color:black;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg p {font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:14px; line-height:24px;}
.first-character {font-weight:400; float: left; font-size: 84px; line-height: 64px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}

.sc {color: #3b8595;}
.ny {color: #3d3c3a;}
.atw {color: #c48660;}

/* Section - Title */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .title {background:white; padding: 60px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .title h1 {font-size:35px; letter-spacing:8px;}

/* Section - Block */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .block {background: white; padding: 60px; width:820px; margin:0 auto; text-align:justify;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .block-gray {background: #f2f2f2;padding: 60px;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .section-overlay-mask {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.70;}

/* Section - Parallax */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-one {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702909-dec73df255d7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8dGVjaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-two {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432163230927-a32e4fd5a326?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-three {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440688807730-73e4e2169fb8?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1001&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;}

/* Extras */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .line-break {border-bottom:1px solid black; width: 150px; margin:0 auto;}

/* Media Queries */
/**************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 40px; width:620px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px; width:420px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg h2 {font-size:30px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-one, #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-two, #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-three {padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px 15px; width:290px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
     <!-- single item -->
     <div class="item">
      <iframe src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2021-07-08-at-3.17.34-PM.png" style="
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
        display:block;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;"></iframe>
         <h2><%= data[i].CHILDNAME %></h2>
   
         <p><%= data[i].FIRSTNAME %> <%= data[i].LASTNAME %></em>
         </p>
         <form action="/myChildFile" method="GET">
          <input type="hidden" name="childName" value="<%= data[i].CHILDNAME %>">
          <input type="hidden" name="report" value="<%= data[i].REPORT1 %>">
          <button class="add-to-cart" type="submit">VIEW REPORT</button>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
```

as you can see above when you run this, the image inside the iframe is too wide. I believe this has something to do with the width of one of the items inside the CSS. I am not sure how to fix this. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630308/possible-to-shrink-contents-of-iframe/2630467) question show how to resize the contents of an iframe using `transform` and `transform-origin`, but you need to use absolute widths:

```css
iframe {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); 
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); 
  -o-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25, 0.25);
  transform: scale(0.25, 0.25); 
  transform-origin: center top;
  
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
}


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #F2EEE9;
    font: normal 13px/1.5 Georgia, Serif;
    color: #333;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 705px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    float: left;
}
.clear {
    clear: both;
}
.items {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.item {
    background-color: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    width: 205px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 290px;
}
.item img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 16px;
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 5px 0;
}
button {
    border: 1px solid #722A1B;
    padding: 4px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #722A1B;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span {
    float: right;
}
.shopping-cart {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/jigsoar-icons/24/_cart.png') no-repeat 0 0;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,400,700);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,200italic,300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,900italic);

/* Override UGG site */
#main {width: 100%; padding:0;}
.content-asset p {margin:0 auto;}
.breadcrumb {display:none;}

/* Helpers */
/**************************/
.margin-top-10 {padding-top:10px;}
.margin-bot-10 {padding-bottom:10px;}

/* Typography */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg h1 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:24px; font-weight:400; text-transform: uppercase; padding:0; margin:0;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg h2 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:70px; letter-spacing:10px; text-align:center; color:white; font-weight:400; text-transform:uppercase; z-index:10; opacity:.9;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg h3 {font-family:'Oswald', sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:0; font-weight:400; letter-spacing:8px; text-transform: uppercase; color:black;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg p {font-family:'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; font-weight:400; font-size:14px; line-height:24px;}
.first-character {font-weight:400; float: left; font-size: 84px; line-height: 64px; padding-top: 4px; padding-right: 8px; padding-left: 3px; font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;}

.sc {color: #3b8595;}
.ny {color: #3d3c3a;}
.atw {color: #c48660;}

/* Section - Title */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .title {background:white; padding: 60px; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .title h1 {font-size:35px; letter-spacing:8px;}

/* Section - Block */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .block {background: white; padding: 60px; width:820px; margin:0 auto; text-align:justify;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .block-gray {background: #f2f2f2;padding: 60px;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .section-overlay-mask {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: black; opacity: 0.70;}

/* Section - Parallax */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-one {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1593642702909-dec73df255d7?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDF8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8dGVjaHxlbnwwfHwwfA%3D%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: top center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-two {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432163230927-a32e4fd5a326?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;}
#parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-three {padding-top: 200px; padding-bottom: 200px; overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 100%; background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1440688807730-73e4e2169fb8?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1001&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=); background-attachment: fixed; background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -webkit-background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;}

/* Extras */
/**************************/
#parallax-world-of-ugg .line-break {border-bottom:1px solid black; width: 150px; margin:0 auto;}

/* Media Queries */
/**************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 40px; width:620px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px; width:420px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg h2 {font-size:30px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px;}
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-one, #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-two, #parallax-world-of-ugg .parallax-three {padding-top:100px; padding-bottom:100px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  #parallax-world-of-ugg .block {padding: 30px 15px; width:290px;}
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
     <!-- single item -->
     <div class="item">
      <iframe src="https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Screen-Shot-2021-07-08-at-3.17.34-PM.png" style="
        display:block;
        background-size: cover;
        border-radius: 8px 0 0 8px;"></iframe>
         <h2><%= data[i].CHILDNAME %></h2>
   
         <p><%= data[i].FIRSTNAME %> <%= data[i].LASTNAME %></em>
         </p>
         <form action="/myChildFile" method="GET">
          <input type="hidden" name="childName" value="<%= data[i].CHILDNAME %>">
          <input type="hidden" name="report" value="<%= data[i].REPORT1 %>">
          <button class="add-to-cart" type="submit">VIEW REPORT</button>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>
```